# jQuery Parse JSON over multiple levels

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse the following and display a simple output list showing "City, State":

```
{
"status":"success",
"data":[
    {"city":"Brooklyn Park","state":"MN"},
    {"city":"Campbellsport","state":"WI"},
    {"city":"Wauwatosa","state":"WI"},
            ...
    ]
}
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
var output = $.parseJSON(data);
var list = output.data;
$.each(list,function(){
    item = $.parseJSON(list);
    console.log(list.city);
});
```

where the original data is from a callback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$.parseJSON` will parse the entire object, you don't need to parse each element.

```
var output = $.parseJSON(data);
var list = output.data;

$.each(list,function(i,item){
    console.log(item.city);
});
```

Comment: Perfect. Knew it was something stupid. I'll select your answer as soon as SO let's me...

Answer (score 5):

```
var output = $.parseJSON(data);
var list = output.data;
$.each(list,function(index, val){

    // within val you'll get each 
    // data object

    console.log( val.city );
});
```

You not need to parse again within the `$.each()`. Because, `output` is already parsed so you can get the `list` using `output.data`.

Answer (score 0):

data is an array so just use a for loop

```
var output = $.parseJSON(data);
var list = output.data;
for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
    var city = list[i].city;
    var state = list[i].state;
    console.log(city + "," + state);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var output = $.parseJSON(data);
var list = output.data;

$.each(list, function() {
  console.log(this['city']); // could also be this.city
});
```

When you jump into any function like that inside of jQuery you then switch to "this" - the data in each "list" is not getting saved into item correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function (response) {

                       var output = response[0].City;



                       alert(output);

                   }
```

Comment: I think this would help.If you want to get first city then use 0 and keep on increasing number for further cities.

Answer (score 0):

this may help.

```
var json = [
    {"id":"1","tagName":"apple"},
    {"id":"2","tagName":"orange"},
    {"id":"3","tagName":"banana"},
    {"id":"4","tagName":"watermelon"},
    {"id":"5","tagName":"pineapple"}
];

$.each(json, function(idx, obj) {
    alert(obj.tagName);
});
```